# Display data from multiple tables and group them by a value (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple of tables that i feel different data inside based on user inputs, the tables contain different columns, so i want to create like a page something like user activity to show him/her everything what he was doing, now i have a couple of tables that hold data and i need somehow to select all the data based on one account number that all the tables contain it and display to the user based on the date, what i had until now is below:

```html
global $wpdb;
global $userInfo;
$il_wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

This example with 2 tables only, but i have around 6 tables that i need to join them

```
$_IL_TABLE_NAME       = $wpdb->prefix . "il_complaints";
$_IL_TABLE_NAME1       = $wpdb->prefix . "il_internal_transfer";
$_IL_GET_COOKIES_VAL = $userInfo['account'];
//my query
$_IL_QUERY_RESULT = $il_wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $_IL_TABLE_NAME.il_date, $_IL_TABLE_NAME1.il_amount FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME, $_IL_TABLE_NAME1 WHERE $_IL_TABLE_NAME.il_mt4_account='$_IL_GET_COOKIES_VAL' ");
//display data
foreach($_IL_QUERY_RESULT as $_IL_ROW){
    echo $_IL_ROW->il_date;
    echo $_IL_ROW->il_amount;
}
```

Because data will be displaed here from multiple tables how i can put to them something first raw is coming from first table and put to it table 1, the second row is coming from second table and to put to it table 2, to show to the user what he/she did and from where

I will appreciate any help.

**try based on comments**

```html
$_IL_QUERY_RESULT = $il_wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT pr_il_complaints.il_date, pr_il_internal_transfer.il_amount
FROM pr_il_complaints t1 INNER JOIN pr_il_internal_transfer t2 ON t1.il_from_mt4 = t2.il_mt4_account;
");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a SQL JOIN, like this:

```
 SELECT t1.name, t2.salary  
FROM employee AS t1 INNER JOIN info AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;

SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
FROM employee t1 INNER JOIN info t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

More: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: i tried already a lot of example, but let me try with yours @Thiago256

Comment: with your example did not worked, displaying nothing, i put your try in my question  @Thiago256

Comment: Have you tried run a native query in mysql console?

Comment: no i didn't, the second answer is working as i did, actually what i have in my question is working is showing data, but not taking them from all the tables but only from the second table and duplicating the rows and displaying them @Thiago256

Answer (score 0):

**try this...**

```
$mysqli   = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$strr     = "SELECT * FROM table1
             INNER JOIN tabel2
              ON table2.account_number = '".$something."'
             INNER JOIN tabel3
              ON table3.account_number = '".$something."'
            "; 
$result   = $mysqli->query($strr);
while($arr      = $result->fetch_array())
{
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);  echo "</pre>"; 
}
```

Comment: with your example i egt the same as i did, at the moment is taking a row from table 2 and duplicating it and display, all the rows are taken only from table 2 and duplicating them @Ronser

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins

```
SELECT TN.il_date, TN2.il_amount , TNX.field...
FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME TN
JOIN $_IL_TABLE_NAME1 T2 ON TN.ID_FIELD = TN2.ID_FIELD
JOIN $_IL_TABLE_NAMEX TX ON TX.ID_FIELD = DATABASE.FIELD
JOIN ...
WHERE $_IL_TABLE_NAME.il_mt4_account='$_IL_GET_COOKIES_VAL'
```

Extra Information: 
1.-[Sintaxis de JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/join.html)
2.-[Understanding JOINs in MySQL and Other Relational Databases](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: i get the same result, displaying data only from TN2 and duplicating the row @Nigmentreth

Comment: Do you have a field that link every table like id, you try to use LEFT join, and you should try to execute the query first in the database using a database administration program like workbench. try to show the tables structure

Comment: i have a field in first table il_mt4_account that is equal with this field il_from_mt4 from the second table, actually all the tables i want to link i have the same account number everywhere @Nigmentreth

Comment: how many records do you have in the tables 2,3,4,5,6, with the same id, if you have more than one thats why you get the rows duplicated, if you need only one row from each table the query is going to be a little diferent.